# Gobble command not gobbling the arguments of footnotemark (inside a authblk definition)

Tags: macros, footnotes, authblk

I am editing this style for papers and I run into this problem for displaying the authors with the right footnotes. We use the `authblk` package and `thanks` command for defining / displaying authors. The code looks like this

```
 \author[1]{First Author \thanks{Research supported by blah}}
 \author[2]{Second Author \thanks{Research supported by blih}}

 \affil[1]{Department of Mathematics in the University of Lost Dimensions}
 \affil[2]{Department of Computer Science in the Binary Group Institute}
```

This works fine, adding footnote marks for both affiliations and the thanks part (which is an actual footnote)

The problem comes when both authors have the same grant to thank. I want to replace the second `thank` command by a footenotemark referring to the first one. If use directly the `footnotemark` command inside the `author`, it gives an error so I'm using `protect` like this

```
 \author[1]{First Author \thanks{Research supported by blah}}
 \author[2]{Second Author \protect\footnotemark[1]}
```

Then, I'm fine with authors on the front page BUT our style defines the following function to print the name of the authors on other pages

```
\newcommand*{\authors}{%
  \begingroup
    \let\footnote\@gobble% ignore \footnote
    \let\thanks\@gobble% ignore \thanks
    \let\textsuperscript\@gobble% ignore protected \textsuperscript
    \expandafter\let\csname textsuperscript \endcsname\@gobble
    \let\Authfont\relax% do not use a special font
    \def\Authand{, }% separate list of authors by ,
    \ifnum\value{authors}<3 % one ore two authors
      \AB@authlist% show them all
    \else% 3 or more authors
    \ABgetauthor{1}\,et~al.
    \fi
  \endgroup
}
```

If I leave it like this, the second author appears with a footnotemark on later pages. So I add this line inside my authors function

`\let\footnotemark\@gobble% ignore \footnotemark`

Now this appears "First Author, Second Author1]" because the argument of `\footnotemark` is not gobbled by the gobble method. The only hack I found was to use this line instead

`\let\footnotemark\@gobblethree% ignore \footnotemark`

It works but I wonder if there is a better / cleaner way of doing it

Thank you very much for your help

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! It would be easier to understand your question with an compilable short TeX code resulting in your issue ...

Comment: please make a complete small test document, in particular is the code that you show in the scope of `\makeatletter` ?

Comment: if you want to redefine footnotemark to have an optional argument and do nothing then `\renewcommand\footnotemark[1][]{}`

Comment: Thanks! What David proposed worked with the renewcommand
I'm sorry I didn't provide a minimal test document. As it is a homemade style file with a bunch of other stuff, it's difficult to make something work as I run into new problems while trying to make a minimal example. 
The code at the top (the authors command) is in the main document while the definition of authors is in the cy style file

Comment: Probably you wish to do something about the spacing behind the dot of `et~al.` in case this abbreviation does not end a sentence while `\nonfrenchspacing` is in effect. Otherwise something like `\authors\unskip{\null} ` might be needed for proper inter-word-spacing when `\authors` does not end a sentence...

Answer (score 1):

As I got an answer in the comments from David, I am posting it here for more visibility if someone runs into a similar issue.

I changed the definition of the `authors` command using `renewcommand` instead of `gobble`:

```
\newcommand*{\authors}{%
  \begingroup
    \renewcommand\footnotemark[1][]{}% ignore \footnotemark
    \let\footnote\@gobble% ignore \footnote
    \let\thanks\@gobble% ignore \thanks
    \let\textsuperscript\@gobble% ignore protected \textsuperscript
    \expandafter\let\csname textsuperscript \endcsname\@gobble
    \let\Authfont\relax% do not use a special font
    \def\Authand{, }% separate list of authors by ,
    \ifnum\value{authors}<3 % one ore two authors
      \AB@authlist% show them all
    \else% 3 or more authors
    \ABgetauthor{1}\,et~al.
    \fi
  \endgroup
}
```

This code lies in a home made sty files that we use for our papers. Now everything works as intended.